# Optimize macro : table clear content

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working a lot with Excel tables.
I use a very simple macro in order to get table cleared when I try formulas, other macros etc...
As I don't want to delete specified tables, I lock them.
I have between 5000 and 10000 cells to clear and this is very very long as my computer is not really built for this kind of task.

Here is my actual macro which is working well but is there something I can change in order to go quicker?
I know this is quite long to check all cells one by one but do I really have the choice?
I have to precise that a table is totally cleared or not cleared at all (locked)
And I can't precise the name of the table to be cleared or not, hence my choice to go through each table and to clean only when not locked.

```
Sub RaZ_activesheet_table()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim retour As Long
Dim c As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
retour = MsgBox(Prompt:="Vider les tableaux?", Buttons:=vbOKCancel)
If retour = vbOK Then
For Each tbl In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
    For Each c In Range(tbl.Name)
        If c.Locked = False Then
            c.ClearContents
        End If
    Next c
Next tbl
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution.
It's working if :

1. You unlock all your cell first
2. Next, you protect cells that you don't want to clear
3. And finally, you need to add a sheet protection with the both first option

[image]

After that, you can apply this simple code :

```
sub test()
On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = vbNullString
On Error GoTo 0
end sub
```

In you case, you'll have something like this :

```
Sub RaZ_activesheet_table()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim retour As Long
Dim c As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

retour = MsgBox(Prompt:="Vider les tableaux?", Buttons:=vbOKCancel)

    If retour = vbOK Then
        For Each tbl In ActiveSheet.ListObjects

            On Error Resume Next
                tbl.UsedRange.Value = vbNullString
            On Error GoTo 0

        Next tbl
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```